# get minutes and seconds from query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I need a time in minutes and seconds. If minutes is greater than 60 I then add to minutes, but do not convert hours

Query :

```
TO_CHAR((sum(seconds)|| ' second')::interval,'HH24:MI:SS') 
as duration from table;
```

Output:

```
DURATION
02:50:21
```

Required Output:

```
DURATION
170:21
```

even i have tried another query (without HH24) but i get below out put:

Query :

```
TO_CHAR((sum(seconds)|| ' second')::interval,'MI:SS') as duration from table;
```

Output:

```
DURATION
50:21
```

Here we can see  from 1st query output 02 hrs means 120 minutes + 50minutes  =170 minutes  and seconds same as it is.

is it possible directly getting from query or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need `to_char` here:

```
select (sum(seconds) / 60)::text || ':' || (sum(seconds) % 60) ...;
```